# How to animate forward, wait x seconds, animate back and then remove the class?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I'm trying to apply an animation for my button, but I can't get it to animate backwards, i.e. when the class is removed. It only animates forwards.

Basically what I need to do is:

- Add the class
- Wait 4 seconds
- Remove the class

But the animation should animate back before the class is removed.

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT:** The only solutions I find is by using different classes for this, but I feel that there must be a better way. I don't want to have to deal with more than 1 class, if possible.
This is my attempt:

```
doStuff = function() {

  /... some code .../

  button.classList.add('btn-success-msg');

  setTimeout(function() {
    button.classList.remove('btn-success-msg');
  }, 4000);
}

@keyframes btn-message {

  0% {
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }

  100% {
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}

.btn-success-msg {
  position: relative;

  &:before {
    @include pos(0, $left: 0);
    content: 'Success!';
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid $success;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: $success;
    color: white;
    animation: btn-message 500ms forwards;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do explain how this is "off-topic"..

Comment: You could achieve this by enforcing your knowledge of the basics. I recommend watching some tutorials about this kind of stuff. It's always a good idea to improve! But unfortunately you will get downvoted here.

Comment: @Shadetheartist I know the basics obviously or I wouldn't even have gotten the forward animation to work, would I?.. Also see updated question.

Comment: Trying to wrap my head around this. But I think you can reverse the animation with animation direction **and then** remove the class... ?

Comment: @AnkithAmtange Was thinking that too, but can you delay the animation once it reaches one end?

Comment: @chri I'm not trying to criticize, sorry. Perhaps the 'basics' are below this questions' level. But to do this, using two classes is actually quite standard. I understand your reluctance to add complexity to your app, and  it's good that you think that way.

Comment: Yes, can delay the animation half way and then go back by adding more steps, 0%, 10%, 20% etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using transitions, not animations, to achieve this effect. Transitions happen when attributes are changed, so when a class is added or removed, it can trigger a transition. Additionally, if the class is removed before the transition completes, it will reverse the transition automatically without skipping.

```js
var testing = $('.testing');

// after 1 second, add a class
setTimeout(function() {
    testing.addClass('animate');
}, 1000);

// after 4 seconds, remove the class
setTimeout(function() {
    testing.removeClass('animate');
}, 4000);
```

```css
.testing {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  
  transition: transform 2s;
}

.animate {
  transform: translateX(200px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="testing">testing</div>
```